# How to clean up an improperly installed SQL server

Tags: sql, automated-install

I have a Win2003 64 bit server.  Trying to install SQL 2005 Standard.  The install tells me a previous install is still pending.  I've rebooted to no avail.  There is no SQL version listed in Add/Remove.

I've removed the support files, native client and C++.  It should be noted that the uninstall took over 45 minuts for each of them as it would hang around 90%

Answer (score 1):

Try hunting through the registry for any rubbish it's left behind there.  Start with what's under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: +1 Good tip. This is where I go as a last resort. SQL 2008's installer is somewhat better, thankfully!